# Laravel/Eloquent enforce findOrFail and safeOrFail

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

`MyModel::find()` and  `MyModel::save()` do not throw any exception when nothing happens, so it's up to the calling code to validate that, which usually does not happen.  I extend MyModel from an AbstractModel where I define:

```php
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class AbstractModel extends Model
{
    public static function find()
    {
        return parent::findOrFail();
    }

    public static function save()
    {
        return parent::saveOrFail();
    }
}
```

Is it that the right solution or is there any other way to enforce the fail?

Comment: i would argue whenever you need this functionality use findOrFail or saveOrFail, there is cases where find and save will come in handy, what to do when you want to use them?

Comment: just call `findOrFail` ... and `find`/`findOrFail` are not methods on Model they are on Eloquent Builder

Comment: It just feels so verbose and very easy to forget to always have to add the `orFail`

Comment: because it isn't `find` it is `findOrFail` it has different functionality